# Reflecting updated & deleted rows using Sqoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have transaction data stored in MySQL which gets inserted/updated/deleted everyday. I plan to push the data into HDFS and later query using Hive. **Is there a way I can deal with updates and deletes on Hive reflecting the changes made to the MySQL table ??** For transferring data between MySQL to Hive I use Sqoop and to the best of my knowledge Sqoop doesn't support updates/deletes though it supports incremental imports.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use a temporary hive table, and then use insert overwrite to the target hive table. It is ideal here is to use partitions because using insert overwrite you will delete ALL the data stored in that partition

Comment: Hi Miguel, thanks for the reply.. That is one of the current options in my mind. Isnt there a robust solution provided by sqoop itself? I believe this is a workaround.. Surprising that all these years there is no direct update/delete approach that can scan tables and appropriately reflect the changes.
Any solutions oriented to the above requirement? Thanks again :)